# Magento 2.3.3 + elasticsearch 6 - empty catalog. Elasticsearch adds WHERE (NULL) to product collection

Tags: magento2.3, elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch 6.8 and M2.3.3.
On the both category and search pages Magento display:

`We can't find products matching the selection.`

(MYSQL engine works correctly)

Reindex and cache are refreshed. I also added 2 patches:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/27112#issuecomment-748916677

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/release-notes-2-3-3-open-source.html#apply-the-catalog-pagination-issue-on-elasticsearch-6x-patch-to-resolve-a-critical-search-result-pagination-issue

Elasticseach is configured properly:

`curl -X GET http://elasticsearch:9200/test_product_1_v15/_search?q=sergei`

```
{"took":7,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":4.255225,"hits":[{"_index":"test_product_1_v15","_type":"document","_id":"246","_score":4.255225,"_source":{"store_id":"1","sku":"Sergey","status":"1","status_value":"Enabled","visibility":"4","name":"Sergey","category_ids":[2,52,84,125],"position_category_2":"0","name_category_2":"Test Category","position_category_52":"0","name_category_52":"Test Category 2","position_category_84":"0","name_category_84":"Test Category 3","position_category_125":"0","name_category_125":"Test","price_4_1":"80.000000","price_0_1":"100.000000","price_1_1":"100.000000","price_2_1":"100.000000","price_3_1":"100.000000","price_5_1":"100.000000","price_6_1":"100.000000"}}]}}
```

Here is the final SQL query from list.phtml - it contains strange condition `WHERE (NULL)`

```
SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, IFNULL(review_summary.reviews_count, 0) AS `reviews_count`, IFNULL(review_summary.rating_summary, 0) AS `rating_summary` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `review_entity_summary` AS `review_summary` ON e.entity_id = review_summary.entity_pk_value AND review_summary.store_id = 1 AND review_summary.entity_type = (SELECT `review_entity`.`entity_id` FROM `review_entity` WHERE (entity_code = 'product')) WHERE (NULL)
```

Without this condition all seems fine.

I logged collection in this method (I suppose it's elasticsearch output(?)):  `\Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Layer\Category\ItemCollectionProvider::getCollection()`

and `WHERE (NULL)` already here:

```
SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` WHERE (NULL)
```

Any ideas why elastic search adds this condition and how can I rightly discard it?

If elastic search (magento extension) adds NULL because the answer from elastic search is empty, how can I debug it in magento?

Comment: Weird, I have elasticsearch running in version 6.8.13 with magento 2.3.5-p without this problem. Dumb question, but have you tried to reindex and/or restart elasticsearch service?

Comment: I am going through the same issue. Please let me know if you get to a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find the solution. The problem was gone after upgrade to magento 2.4. The elasticsearch was upgraded too.

Comment: @GustavoUlyssea Have you found any solution

Comment: Hello @Pawankumar unfortunately not.